# Get store modules list

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Is there a shorter/cleaner way to get the list of Vuex store modules than:

```js
var modules = this.$store._modules.root._children;
modules = Object.keys(modules);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the names of the modules?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Exactly